# Why does this rewrite rule require *.*

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect requests for any images with filenames starting with a string like 'myimage_' to a subdirectory on another server. I'd like to understand why the following rule does not work for my use case.

```
RewriteRule ^img/app/(gi_*)$ http://images.mydomain.com/targetdir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but this one does:

```
RewriteRule ^img/app/(myimage_*.*)$ http://images.mydomain.com/targetdir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

`mod_rewrite` uses [regular expressions (or "RegEx")](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to match rewrite rule input, and in a regular expression `*` is not a wildcard. `*` simply means "match the preceding token zero or more times" - in this case the preceding token is `_` so `img/app/gi` will return a match, as will `img/app/gi___`.

In regex, `.` is a wildcard character, which is why `.*` works, but `*` alone does not.

Comment: of course! thanks, was forgetting regex and thinking of the old DOS *.* meaning 'all files'. I think I could therefore improve it with myimage_*.*\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)